# When we use StandardScaler() in Pipeline with GridSearchCV, does it automatically take care of data leakage in k-fold CV?

Tags: scikit-learn

A lot of tutorials use pipeline with GridSearchCV. Example [here](https://medium.com/@cmukesh8688/sklearn-pipeline-gridsearchcv-54f5552bbf4e).

```
pipeline = Pipeline([( "scaler" , StandardScaler()),
                       ("rf",RandomForestClassifier())])
parameters = {
  'n_estimators':[1,10,100,1000],
  'min_samples_split': [2,3,4,5]
  }

grid_pipeline = GridSearchCV(pipeline,parameters,cv=5)

grid_pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

If we do this, does GridSearchCV properly do k-fold CV on it's own without data leakage?

What I mean by proper?

- For Fold 1 as validation set, use StandardScaler.fit_transform() on
  the 4 folds, and only StandardScaler.transform() on Fold 1 which is
  the validation set.
- Process repeats for other 4 folds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. [The docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.predict) for `Pipeline.predict` mentions that each transformer only calls `transform`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "each transformer" means here.

Comment: Each step of the pipeline, except _perhaps_ the last, is a transformer.